Use dayofweek user input
I'm trying to highlight a specific day of the week and I want the day to be user definable. I'm getting errors related to type casting but don't know how to fix it. THis is my code:
enum days
    monday = "Monday"
    tuesday = "Tuesday"
    wednesday = "Wednesday"
    thursday = "Thursday"
    friday = "Friday"

aDay = input.enum(days.monday, 'Day', group = 'A')
bgcolor((dayofweek == aDay) ? color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 75) : na, title = "A")


input.enum returns enum and dayofweek is of type int. So, you need to convert your input to an int.
enum_to_int(e) =>
    switch (e)
        days.monday => 2
        days.tuesday => 3
        days.wednesday => 4
        days.thursday => 5
        days.friday => 6
        => 0

day_int = enum_to_int(aDay)

bgcolor((dayofweek == day_int) ? color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 75) : na, title = "A")


Thank you very much. Would you know how to highlight candles in the future? For example, can I highlight coming friday on the chart where there is no candle? I can't find any info on this
